# Скрыть один язык из адреса в htaccess. Laravel

Tags: .htaccess

```
http://example.com/en/xxx
http://example.com/ru/xxx
http://example.com/de/xxx
```

Английский необходимо скрыть:
http://example.com/xxx - должен работать как http://example.com/en/xxx

Необходимо что-то вроде:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L]
```

Но чтобы применять только к /en/xxx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://example.com/xxx` меняем на `http://example.com/en/xxx`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?![a-z]{2}\/)(.*)$ /en/$1 [L]
```

Только `http://example.com/en/xxx` меняем на `http://example.com/xxx`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(en\/)(.*)$ /$2 [L]
```

Потестить можно здесь [ссылка](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=18f774f2-c25b-4261-b6f0-91c5f56bba9d)